# Горизонтальный скролл фиксированного элемента

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте, друзья!
Ситуация такая: сделал фиксированный хедер, который остается на своем месте при вертикальном скролле (с помощью position:fixed).
Проблема: верстка не адаптивная, поэтому при уменьшении экрана хедер обрезается справа и его не проскроллить горизонтально вместе с основным контентом.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую проблему?

Comment: хорошо бы код увидеть.

Но думаю стоит задать ему ширину + макс и мин ширину.

Comment: @MaksDevda Добавил ответ с кодом

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<header class="top_head_wrap">

    <div class="top_head">


        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="what_is_link">Что это?</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="types_link">Типы проколов</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="why_us_link">Наши преимущества</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="how_working_link">Как мы работаем</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="reviews_link">Отзывы</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>


        <a href="#form" class="request magnific_popup_form">Заказать обратный звонок</a>

        <div class="top_head_right">
            <p> +7 (901) 23-45-678</p>
            <p> с 09:00 до 23:00 без выходных</p>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.top_head_wrap {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 60px;
    max-width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}


.top_head {
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 1024px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}



.top_head nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.top_head nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.top_head nav ul li:last-type {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.top_head nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.top_head nav ul li a:hover {
    color: #e34b68;
}

.request {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: #e34b68 1px solid;
    margin-left: 80px;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.request:hover {    
    color: #e34b68;
}

.top_head_right {
    margin-left: -80px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    float: right;
}

.top_head_right p {
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;

}

.top_head_right p:first-child {
    color: #e34b68;
    font-family: "DinProRegular";
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```